# Establish connection does not work with Ruby console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have configured `database.yml` to include "logging_development" as a label for signifying another database. One of the models is using "establish_connection" to connect to the database using this "label".

My model looks like this:

class AdHistory < ActiveRecord::Base

establish_connection "logging_#{RAILS_ENV}"

The Rails server works fine when it starts and establishes connection of the model with the concerned database. But when I start ruby console and try to use the model, it uses "development" label in `database.yml` to establish connections. I have looked into the issue but unable to find a solution. Here is a sample of the `database.yml` file:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  database: ad_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: ********
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

logging_development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  database: ad_logging
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: ********
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I am using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.8

Answer (score 1):

Have you used the RAILS_ENV=logging_development when running the rails console? If not you should, because the default Rails environment is `development`. So, try to load the console using this to set the RAILS_ENV variable:

`RAILS_ENV=logging_development scripts/rails console`

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I understand what you are saying about the default environment to be "development" for ruby console. The model loads - "logging_#{RAILS_ENV}". So, it should be able to connect to "logging_development" even when the default environment is development. I just updated my question to make it clearer.

Comment: It is rather strange but when I remove the "development" label from the database.yml file then the model is able to connect to the concerned database. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question. The problem was that I was using Multi_DB gem which was intercepting all the SQL Queries that were being executed and re-directing those queries to the slave database. That was why those queries were not being executed against the database I had chosen in the "database.yml". Once the multi_db connection is nullified, the console behaves as expected. One of the problems of using "multi_db" gem is that it only accepts names of connections as "_slave_database_". So, any deviation from the expected name for multi_db gem in database.yml file will lead to errors, and the queries will not get executed against the selected database.